# How do I store the absolute value of random numbers in a certain column of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, random, absolute-value

I would like to take the randomized numbers of the first column of my array, find their absolute values, and store them in my second column.
So far i've written this code:

```
import random
nb = int(input("Enter a number : "))
tab = [[random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(nb)], []]
print(','.join(str(n) for n in tab))
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can get the absolute value of numbers using `abs()`, but what about your "second column" I don't understand how or where that fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(nb): tab[1].append(abs(tab[0][i]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But where do I put this line in my code ?

Comment: Just after you have defined tab